# Is the local Berry connection difference gauge invariant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, gauge-invariance, berry-pancharatnam-phase

The Berry connection in terms of the cell-periodic Bloch states $u_{n\mathbf{k}}=e^{-i\mathbf{k \cdot r}}\psi_{n\mathbf{k}}$ with band index $n$ and crystal momentum $\mathbf{k}$ is defined as
$$
A_{n}(\mathbf{k}) = i\langle u_{n\mathbf{k}}|\nabla_{\mathbf{k}}|u_{n\mathbf{k}} \rangle
$$
Which is gauge dependent since if added an arbitrary phase $i\phi(\mathbf{k})|u_{n\mathbf{k}} \rangle$, it would change to $\tilde{A}_{n}(\mathbf{k}) = A_{n}(\mathbf{k}) + \nabla_{\mathbf{k}} \phi(\mathbf{k})$. Now I'm wondering if the difference $A_{n}(\mathbf{k}) - A_{m}(\mathbf{k}) $ between two bands at the same $\mathbf{k}$ point is gauge invariant? The phase canceled out?

Comment: It seems to be so, based on the fact that $\phi(k)$ does not depend on the band index.

Comment: Why $\phi(k)$ does not depend on band index?

Comment: You did not put a $n$ subindex.

Comment: Got you. I'm sorry but in general the phases for different bands are different, right?